# Error al hacer depuración y diagnostico por instrumentación. En visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Error al hacer depuración por diagnostico de instrumentación. En visual studio 2013

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado fue el siguiente

```
Generación de perfiles iniciada.
Instrumentando C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe en contexto
Mensaje informativo VSP3049: las funciones pequeñas se excluirán de la instrumentación.
Instrumentación posterior a la vinculación de Microsoft (R) VSInstr 12.0.30723 x86
(C) Microsoft Corp. Reservados todos los derechos.
Archivos para procesar:
   C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe --> C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe
Se realizó una copia de seguridad del archivo original en C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe.orig
Error VSP1014: No se pudo realizar la operación de E/S de escritura en el archivo 'C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe'.
PRF0002: Error de instrumentación con estas opciones: /u "C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe"   /excludesmallfuncs. Consulte la ventana de salida para obtener detalles adicionales.
Se escribieron datos en C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI160204(4).vsp.
Generación de perfiles finalizada.
El archivo no contiene búferes de datos
El archivo no contiene búferes de datos
Error en el análisis
Generación de perfiles completa.
```

Comment: ¿Haz consultado la ventana de salida para obtener los detalles adicionales? ¿Podrías colocarlos acá para su revisión y así apoyarte más a resolver el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>No se pudo realizar la operación de E/S de escritura en el archivo 'C:\Users\juansp\Dropbox\material de estudio\DesarrolloJuanSP_SAP\ProyectoInterFacesSAP\SAPInterfacesUI\bin\Debug\SAPInterfacesUI.exe'.**

Esta claro que no puedo acceder al archivo, recomendaria pruebes dos cosas

- copies al solución a una carpeta mas corta, a veces si el sln esta dentro de muchas carpetas puede fallar
- que la carpeta de la solucion no tengas espacios

O sea crea una carpeta simple c:\Dev y copia la solucion alli y abrelo con el VS

---

Tambien valida que ninguna otro proceso este tomando el archivo.

Prueba cerrando el VS, ve a la carpeta \bin\Debug y elimina su contenido, vuelve abrir el VS, realiza un Rebuild y vuelve a ejecutar.

Comment: Gracias si era por el por la ruta del archivo

Comment: @AlejandroSoler O sea, movieste la solucion a una carpeta mas corta y funciono ?

Comment: Si la moví a un directorio mas corto